# Wrong dates on Argentina ETA

Tags: indian-citizens, applications, argentina, eta, canadian-residents

I applied for Argentina ETA for travel in late December 2019. I used their web interface to specify the exact travel dates.

I got an approval for ETA valid from July 2019 to October 2019. Apart from emailing their local consulate, is there anything I can do? Anyone else had this issue?

I am an Indian citizen residing in Toronto.

UPDATE: Consulate asked me to email: ave@migraciones.gov.ar which handles all ETA applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems they approve only for approval date + 90 days regardless of when you actually want to travel. They won't change the dates on my ETA and I have to pay the fees again and apply again if I want to travel in December.

Looks like I will be going elsewhere for vacation.

Comment: I have similar problem. Are you allowed to pay again and apply for a new one even while this one is still valid?